# Make customized connections and weights constrains in a Tensorflow neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I want to to build a neural network with some customized requirements. I have an input layer (8 inputs), then a linear hidden layer (2 neurons), then a nonlinear hidden layer (Relu, 10 neurons) and one output. i want the first 4 inputs to contribute exclusively to the first neuron of the first hidden layer and the last 4 inputs to contribute exclusively to the second neuron. Moreover, I want the first 4 weights to be equal to the last 4 weights. See the picture below.

[image: NN]

So here w_1 = w_5, w_2 = w_6, w_3 = w_7, w_4 = w_8

So far, I have tried to put customized constraints on the weights matrix to have zeros and equal elements in appropriate places. But tf.concat doesn't want to concatenate the matrices with rank 1

```
class EqualWeights(tf.keras.constraints.Constraint):
    def __call__(self, w):

        first = w[:4, 1]
        first = tf.concat([first, tf.zeros(4,1)], axis = 0)
        second = tf.concat([tf.zeros(4,1), first], axis = 0)
        
        return tf.concat([first, second], axis = 1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
   layers.Dense(2, input_shape = (8,), activation='linear', kernel_constraint = EqualWeights()),     
   layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'),
   layers.Dense(1)
  ])
  
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
              loss = 'mean_squared_error', 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

This gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be at least rank 2 but is rank 1 for '{{node Adam/concat_2}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](Adam/concat, Adam/concat_1, Adam/concat_2/axis)' with input shapes: [8], [12], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <1>.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you have to fix.

1. you overwrite `first` before you use it in `second` here:

```
first = w[:4, 1]  
first = tf.concat([first, tf.zeros(4,1)], axis = 0)
```

you could fix it like that:

```
first_ = w[:4, 1]  
first = tf.concat([first_, tf.zeros(4,1)], axis = 0)
second = tf.concat([tf.zeros(4,1), first_], axis = 0)
```

2. The shapes of `first` and `second` are `(8,)`, but need to be `(8,1)` for them to concatenate. You could either add:

```
first = tf.expand_dims(first, 1)
second = tf.expand_dims(second, 1)
```

before your `return` call, or change the lines for first and second to:

```
first_ = w[:4, 1:]
first = tf.concat([first_, tf.zeros((4,1))], axis = 0)
second = tf.concat([tf.zeros((4,1)), first_], axis = 0)
```

Notice the `:` after the `w[:4,1` and the additional () in `tf.zeros`. This will both retain the second dimension for your tensors.
Out of curiosity, but what are you trying to do with this network?

Edit: Seeing your picture of the network, I thought about another way which could work. You could treat your two inputs as two really distict network inputs `x` and `y` and use the same dense layer if you want to share the weights between them. This uses the [Keras functional API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/) instead of the Sequential API, which is not as straightforward, but allows multiple inputs, outputs and branches in the network.

```
input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(x.shape[1:])
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(y.shape[1:])
d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
x2 = d1(input1)
y2 = d1(input2)
concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate((x2,y2))
d2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(concat)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=d2)
```

I have to say, I'm not sure how the model handles the layer re-use, and for both solutions I'm not sure how backpropagation works with shared input for one layer or the layer constrain respectively.

Comment: Nice, perfect! Basically, I have some device which transmits electrical signals that he gets from other devices. The device has 2 inputs (2 paramteres describing the state of the electrical signals), which should be linear combinations of the other input devices.  I have to learn the nonlinear output of the device

Comment: I edited my answer for another possible solution. Mind that I never re-used a layer for multiple inputs in the way you want, so I'm not 100% sure it works. But as the two inputs share the same dense layer, they should also share its weights. This could be a more elegant way than the weight constrain overwrite.